# PR trigger not working with Azure DevOps and GitHub

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have my repos hosted on GitHub and running the pipeline on Azure DevOps, it is an iOS pipeline and I am not getting any error but while I try to raise a PR GitHub always gives a warning that I have conflicts and I have to make changes in the main branch as well, which I don't want to do since it might break the workflow is there any work-around for raising the pr without getting the conflict warning?
This is my YAML file:

```
pool:
  vmImage: macOS-latest
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - epic/*
# trigger on PR builds targeting any branches
pr:
  autoCancel: true
  branches:
    include: ['*']      

# Adding parameters to Run UI 
parameters:
- name: FIID
  displayName: FIID
  type: string
  default: 00516
  values:
  - 00516
  - 00031
```

This is the kind of conflict I am getting, I don't know what I might be doing wrong but I don't want to make changes in the develop branch everytime I have to raise a PR for xcodepipeline

[image: This is the kind of conflict I am getting, I don't know what I might be doing wrong but I don't want to make changes in the develop branch everytime I have to raise a PR for xcodepipeline]
If anyone could help me out that would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Merge develop into your feature branch, fix the conflicts, push the changes. The PR should work like a charm after that.

This link should be useful https://akshayranganath.github.io/Git-Pull-Handling-Merge-Conflict/